# Gif Rendering Problem IE

Tags: internet-explorer, rendering, gif

I have a problem with a GIF that will not render properly in IE.

https://www.icm.org.uk/images/stories/468x60px_no_image_v2.gif

In every other browser tested it renders nad animates fine but in IE (tested in IE8) the final frame with the border (and perhaps the other frames although it would not be so obvious) renders wrongly. The right hand border is missing and the bottom border seems to be stretched and almost as if pixels were missing here and there.

Does anyone know why this is and how to get around it?

Cheers,

Rich

Comment: Looks just fine in IE9, FWIW.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question it appears that inside the GIF the three frames were all a pixel short in width and height than the overall GIF dimension this left a pixel of transparency on the right and bottom edge.  It appears IE8 can't handle this for some reason.